# jQuery Dropdown Animation slideUp

Tags: jquery, animation, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

I have navigation menu with jQuery animation. The slideOut animation is ok, but the slideIn animation is not working, also i want to add delay to the slideIn.
Here is the jQuery code:

```
function mainmenu() {
$(" #menu ul ").css(display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
$("#menu li").hover(function() {
$(this).find('ul:first').css({ visibility: "visible", display: "none"}).slideDown(300);}, 
function() {
$(this).find('ul:first').slideUp(400);
});
}
$(document).ready(function() {mainmenu();});
```

...and the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dzadze/ak5mu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working jsfiddle, it has to do with your `display:none` css

http://jsfiddle.net/ak5mu/2/

Comment: The only thing I would add is before both calls to .css, put in .stop() so you don't queue up animations.